# Magento rewrite 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select' not working?

Tags: overrides

below is my config files code.

> app/code/local/Eventprice/Meta/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eventprice_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Eventprice_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eventprice_meta>
                <class>Eventprice_Meta_Model</class>
            </eventprice_meta>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <eventprice_sql>
                <setup>
                    <module>Eventprice_Meta</module>
                </setup>
            </eventprice_sql>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml> 
        <rewrite>
            <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
                Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select
            </catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
            <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_option
            </catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

below the code of my Select.php file.

> app/code/local/Eventprice/Meta/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Type/Select.php

```
<?php

class Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select 
extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Abstract
        {
            /**
             * Class constructor
             */
             public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
                echo 'dsfdsfsd';exit;
                $this->setTemplate('sphere/catalog/product/edit/options/type/select.phtml');
                $this->setCanEditPrice(true);
                $this->setCanReadPrice(true);
            }
        }
 ?>
```

but my module Select.php file is not called. please help where i create a mistake Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write rewrite code of block under the block tag like below

```
<global>
    [.....]
    <blocks>
        <eventprice_meta>
            <class>Eventprice_Meta_Block</class>
        </eventprice_meta>
        <adminhtml> 
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
                    Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select
                </catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
                <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                    Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_option
                </catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

add try changing

```
class Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select
```

**Note:-** For more information on overriding magento core blocks in magento refer http://magento-online-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-override-mageadminhtmlblockcatal.html

Comment: Hi Pradeep i added your code but not working Select.php file is not called fomr my module thanks.

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: your extends class name is wrong

Comment: i changed my class name but then after not working Thanks

Comment: have you added <blocks> code in under <global tag> ?

Comment: no soory let me check.

Comment: like i had now updated in the answer

Comment: Hey man great this is working but on custom_options tab not display anything or else not print 'dsfdsfsd' this string.

Comment: please accest my answer

Comment: ok now help yaar in custom option tab not display anything.

Comment: you had added exit code thats y u may not able to see or try to add exit after settemplate

Comment: hey, it print this error.  'Bundle with dynamic pricing cannot include custom defined options. Options will not be saved.'